# AtTask API how to exclude field

Tags: attask, workfront-api

When requesting specific fields in a GET request, there are default fields that are included as well. I'm specifically talking about the Updates collection on the Task object.

If I send the following query:

> attask/api/task/search?fields=updates:entryDate

The updates that are returned, for some reason, include a number of other fields, including "message", which could be quite large.

Is there are way to have the API exclude one or more of those "default" fields that are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not the default fields will display always fields will only include additional fields.

There are 3 types of fields that will display when you make an api Call

1. Always visible(default)
2. Visible when fields is not specified (These contain some additional fields along with the default
3. Fields listed when called specifically with fields=

Since message falls into the 1st type it will always display no matter what is defined in the fields variable.

Comment: Thanks for the info.